# React testing error 'unable to find element with the text

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-test-renderer

I'm struggling to get my 2nd React test to pass.

#### Here is my App.js file:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {useState} from 'react';
import {Link, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import Home  from "./pages/home.js";
import Products  from './pages/products.js';
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Nav from './nav.js'
import './MaterialDesign-Webfont-master/css/materialdesignicons.css';


function App() {

const productArray = []

productArray[0] = new Image()
productArray[0].src = 'imgs/smartphone-one.jpg'
productArray[0].dataset.key = '0'
productArray[0].alt = 'Blueberry 5000 S'
productArray[0].dataset.price = '£499.99'


productArray[1] = new Image ()
productArray[1].src = 'imgs/smartphone-two.jpg'
productArray[1].dataset.key = '1'
productArray[1].alt = 'Banana 12'
productArray[1].dataset.price = '£999.99'

productArray[2] = new Image()
productArray[2].src = 'imgs/smartphone-three.jpg'
productArray[2].dataset.key = '2'
productArray[2].alt = 'Meg 3'
productArray[2].dataset.price = '£799.99'

productArray[3] = new Image ()
productArray[3].src = 'imgs/smartphone-four.jpg'
productArray[3].dataset.key = '3'
productArray[3].alt = 'Communicator 5000'
productArray[3].dataset.price = '£399.99'

productArray[4] = new Image ()
productArray[4].src = 'imgs/smartphone-five.jpg'
productArray[4].dataset.key = '4'
productArray[4].alt = 'Simplex 2'
productArray[4].dataset.price = '£99.99'

  return ( 
<HashRouter>
<Nav/> 
<div>
  <Routes>

<Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
<Route path="/products" element={<Products 
prods={productArray}/>}

/>
  </Routes>
  </div>
  </HashRouter>
  )
}

export default App;
```

#### Here is my Products component file rendered in App above:

```
import React from 'react-dom'

function Products({prods}) {
 
    return (
        <>
        <h2 className="products-title">Products</h2>
<div className="products" data-testid="products-div">
        {prods.map(prod => {
         return <div className="product" style = {{
            backgroundImage: `url("${prod.src}")`,
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
       display: 'flex',
       flexFlow: 'column nowrap',
       alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
            backgroundPosition: 'top',
            backgroundSize: 'contain',
      
        }} id = {prod.dataset.key} >  
    <p className="prod-copy">{prod.alt}</p>
    <p className="prod-price">{prod.dataset.price}</p>
    
              <button className="add">Add to cart</button>
        </div>
       
        })}
         
        </div>
      
        </>
    )

  }
  
  export default Products;
```

#### And here is my App.test.js file

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';
import React from "react";
import Products from './App'


test('Product in nav',  () => {
 
  render(<App />)
expect(screen.getByText('Products')).toBeInTheDocument()

});



test('phones',  () => {
 
  render(<App />)
expect(screen.getByText('£499,99')).toBeInTheDocument()

});
```

The first test passes, it gets the string 'Products' from the nav bar. There is a div lower down in the DOM with heading 'Products' also - but it doesn't find this when I test by dataset-id - the same with how the second test fails. I've searched high and low but cannot find a solution. I've tried async and await.

Most interestingly, when I do screen.debug(), it doesn't seem to be picking up my <Products /> component, it's like it's not rendered in the DOM when it is I can see all the content on the page loaded. It picks up the <Home/> component though which loads in the <Routes> - is it something to do with this?

For the 2nd test to pass

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, node.js test environments are not DOM environments, and since the `App` component is rendering the router, you've no control over what the current URL is to set the path to `"/products"` so the `Products` component is rendered.

You've a couple options:

1. Unit test `Products` correctly in isolation.

   ```
   test('phones', () => {
     const productArray = [.......];

     render(<Products prods={productArray}/>);
     expect(screen.getByText('£499,99')).toBeInTheDocument();
   });
   ```
2. Refactor the `App` component so it's easier to provide a ***different*** router for testing purposes. Basically this means removing the `HashRouter` from the `App` component.

   ```
   import logo from './logo.svg';
   import './App.css';
   import { useState } from 'react';
   import { Link, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
   import Home  from "./pages/home.js";
   import Products  from './pages/products.js';
   import Nav from './nav.js'
   import './MaterialDesign-Webfont-master/css/materialdesignicons.css';

   function App() {
     const productArray = []

     ...

     return ( 
       <>
         <Nav /> 
         <div>
           <Routes>
             <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
             <Route
               path="/products"
               element={<Products prods={productArray} />}
             />
           </Routes>
         </div>
       </>
     )
   }

   export default App;
   ```

   In the actual app code you still import the `HashRouter` and wrap `App` in order to provide a routing context.

   ```
   import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

   ...
   <HashRouter>
     <App />
   </HashRouter>
   ```

   For unit testing purposes import and use the [`MemoryRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/memory-router) and provide the initial routes and the current route index.

   ```
   import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
   import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
   import App from './App';
   import React from "react";
   import Products from './App';

   test('Product in nav', () => {
     render(
       <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/products"]}>
         <App />
       </MemoryRouter>
     );
     expect(screen.getByText('Products')).toBeInTheDocument();
   });

   test('phones', () => {
     render(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/products"]}>
         <App />
       </MemoryRouter>
     );
     expect(screen.getByText('£499,99')).toBeInTheDocument();
   });
   ```